# Deriving formula for function F(g,h,n) such that (g^a)%N = h%N

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponentiation

I have a maths / coding assignment in which I am required to write a code to find the value of `a` for given values of `g,h and N` such that:

`(g^a)%N = h%N`

where `%` operator returns the remainder after dividing the 2 numbers (example: 5%2 = 1)

Since there is no other information given,I can't convert the equation to `g^a = N.m + h%N` where m is another integer used to reverse the modulus process.

How can I derive a formula for `a`?

Answer (score 0):

Your equation `(g^a)%N = h%N` is equivalent to

$$g^a \equiv h \pmod N$$

The problem of finding $a$ is known as the discrete logarithm, and [no efficient algorithm is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Algorithms). The simplest way to find the smallest solution is to write a loop checking each `(g^a)%N` until it is equal to `h%N`.

However $g^a$ gets large quite quickly. You can use the fact that `(g*((g^a)%N))%N = g^(a+1)%N` to make the numbers involved smaller.